# Create binary array from list of indexes in Python

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I have a list of indexes, say [3,4,7,9]. What is the fastest way to create a binary array (in this case [0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1]).
Thanks!

Comment: Each decimal digit corresponds to an index of 1 in a binary array. I can do this using "for" loop but there must be a faster approach.

Answer (score 3):

With numpy:

```
l = [3,4,7,9]
m = np.zeros(max(l)+1)
m[l] = 1
```

```
>>> m
array([0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1.])
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple list comprehension will do it:

```
indices = {3, 4, 7, 9}
[i in indices for i in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a comprehension:

```
indices = {3,4,7,9}
output = [int(i in indices) for i in range(max(indices)+1)]
```

Comment: This has poor time complexity. `indices` should be a set.

Comment: very nice. Thanks!